# ATX LGA1151 Motherboard /w Stability Primary Concern

Tags: motherboard

This is for a desktop, do not plan any overclocking. Usage is primarily media consumption, photo/video editing, casual gaming. Operating system Windows 10 x64 Professional. Price range looking up to $200 USD. (Consider more for  reliability benefit)

Planned components include:

- [Intel i7-6700](http://ark.intel.com/products/88196/Intel-Core-i7-6700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz)
- M.2 512GB SSD
- 4 SATA HDDs
- [nVidia GeForce GTX 950](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-950/specifications)
- 2x8GB DDR4 RAM

Motherboard should include at least one USB3.1 Type A + Type C

Onboard Bluetooth & Wi-Fi is a plus but not a requirement.

I've been looking primarily at Gigabyte/ASUS boards (because that's what I'm familiar with) but the selection is overwhelming, and unfortunately spec sheets don't cover stability/reliability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASUS Sabertooth Z170 Mark I is what you are looking for. It is around $250 but what you are getting is worth the money. First of all, there is a plastic shield on the front for protection against the chips of the motherboard and there is a metal shield on the back to protect against ESD and board flex. The power delivery components are all tested with a military standard and a report sheet with the tests your motherboard passed is included. There are 2 small, but powerful, fans to cool the power delivery components to prevent them from overheating and extending their life span. It also comes with a 5 year warranty (2 more years than the standard boards).